# Array in Vuex Store (state) throws error in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, vuex

When defining an array in `vuex` store as follows:

```
const state = {
  tags: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Both *Internet Explorer 11* and *Micrsoft Edge* give back a blank page and the following error message:

> `Error: “Unknown name” error in vue.esm.js`

No problems with Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera.

When removing the values, it works:

```
const state = {
  tags: []
}
```

I am using babel-polyfill (main.js: import 'babel-polyfill'). My package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@xkeshi/image-compressor": "^0.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bulma": "^0.6.1",
    "bulma-extensions": "^0.5.2",
    "cropperjs": "^1.2.1",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-rc.27",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.8.0",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^5.0.5",
    "vue-goodshare": "^0.9.3",
    "vue-masonry": "^0.10.16",
    "vue-meta": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-upload-component": "^2.7.4",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.3.11",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.8.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.4.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^4.14.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "semver": "^5.4.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.8",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "uglify-es": "^3.3.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.6.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

I get the same error when using `vuex-persistedstate`.

Comment: can you share full error message , as may be its not issue of that and issue where you are using those values

Comment: This is the error message I get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995592/blank-page-and-unknown-name-error-in-vue-esm-js-microsoft-ie-11-and-microsoft

Comment: Hmm not sure why its happening , when i get free I will try your package file and create project then test it on IE11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blank page and "Unknown name" error in vue.esm.js (Microsoft IE 11 and Microsoft Edge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995592/blank-page-and-unknown-name-error-in-vue-esm-js-microsoft-ie-11-and-microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem - this was my mistake - it was a syntax error in my v-for loop key...